# Array con estructura correcta

Tags: php, jquery, array

tengo el siguiente problema: Necesito generar un array en PHP, previamente los elementos del array son recogidos en un formulario con Jquery, genero el array y lo envío por ajax a PHP

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"../php/prueba.php",
  data:{'mi_array':JSON.stringify(checkedBox)},
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
```

});

En PHP recibo el array de esta manera:

```
$tipo_tienda = array(
    array(
        "tipo_tienda" => json_decode($_POST['mi_array'])
    )
);
```

Esto me debería generar un array con un número de elementos de acuerdo al número de tipos de tienda que haya elegido en el formulario, pero el problema es que la estructura del array generado en PHP, es esta:

```
array(1) {
    [0] => array(1) {
        ["tipo_tienda"] => array(2) {
            [0] => string(7) "tienda1"
            [1] => string(7) "tienda2"
            }
        }
   }
```

Pero para continuar con el resto de operaciones, necesito que la estructura sea esta:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => array(1) {
        ["tipo_tienda"] => string(7) "tienda1"
    }
    [1] => array(1) {
         ["tipo_tienda"] => string(7) "tienda2"
         }
    }
```

El array anterior correcto,lo genero si lo hago manualmente de la siguiente manera:

```
$tipo_tienda = array(
    array(
        "tipo_tienda" => 'tienda1'
    ),
    array(
        "tipo_tienda" => 'tienda2'
    )
);
```

El problema está aquí, en cómo genero el array en php obtenido desde Jquery:

```
$tipo_tienda = array(
    array(
        "tipo_tienda" => json_decode($_POST['mi_array'])
    )
);
```

Alguna sugerencia de cómo crearlo correctamente con la estructura que necesito?

Gracias :)

Comment: Hola y si intentas parcear tu array a JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Al final en la parte del PHP, donde quería obtenerla estructura del array, he utilizado un **foreach** para recorrer el array que venía de Jquery,lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach ($tipo_tienda as $key) {
            "tipo_tienda => " . $key;
        }
```

De esa manera he conseguido la estructura deseada.

De todas formas, muchas gracias a todos :)